# Generating X509v(1/3) certificates in java (bouncy castle)

Tags: java, maven, ssl, certificate, bouncycastle

After reading [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938079/generating-x509certificate-using-bouncycastle-x509v3certificatebuilder) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466489/generating-x-509-certificate-using-bouncy-castle-java-api) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925377/generate-certificates-public-and-private-keys-with-java) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634124/how-to-generate-sign-and-import-ssl-certificate-from-java) on generating X509 certificates using bouncy castle I found that the **X509V1CertificateGenerator** class documented [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation) is deprecated and tried to use the current version, **X509v1CertificateBuilder**, as suggested [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/BC+Version+2+APIs). The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a package **cert** as mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/X509v3CertificateBuilder.html). I am using maven to retrieve bouncy castle:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.53</version>
</dependency>
```

In which package is **X509v1CertificateBuilder** located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bouncy castle also needs: **bcpkix-jdk15on**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.47</version>
</dependency>
```